# Vertical rotate image in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I vertically rotate an image using only `Canvas` (without WebGL etc.)?

I'm looking at something like `-webkit-transform: rotateY();` in CSS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit: Oops!  I think I misunderstood your question. You want to flip with 3D effect, just without webGL.]

**Yes, you can do 3D rotations in canvas without webGL.**

Several canvas libraries offer 3D canvas rotation...

Take a look and K3D (NICE effects!): http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/canvask3d/k3d_test.html

Take a look at GreenSock: http://www.greensock.com/css3/

If you don't want *any* libraries at all, check out K3D.  It's license is liberal enough to allow you to pull out the rotating code you need.

.

.

[My original answer below is probably off-track of what you want--but I'll leave it here anyway]

Here's how to vertically flip a canvas image

When you want to flip vertically, you ironically are flipping on the horizontal axis.

To flip on the horizontal axis you use context.scale like this:

```
context.scale(1,-1);  // flip vertically--using the HORIZONTAL axis !
```

Here's code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/JBCGC/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvasH=document.getElementById("canvasH");
    var ctxH=canvasH.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
      // flip on the horizontal axis
      // (causes upside down)
      canvasH.width=img.width;
      canvasH.height=img.height;
      ctxH.save();
      ctxH.scale(1,-1);
      ctxH.translate(0,-img.height);
      ctxH.drawImage(img,0,0);
      ctxH.restore();
    }
    img.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/houseIcon.png";


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvasH" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this -

```
  // translate context to center of canvas
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  // rotate 45 degrees clockwise
  context.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
```

The rotate transformation requires an angle in radians.
[Reference](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transform-rotate-tutorial/)

Comment: It's not that. I must rotate context in Y Axis, not clockwise.

Answer (score -1):

I like @markE answer, just figured I would post this one as well. It allows you to rotate the image to whatever angle you need.

```
function rotate(angle) {
    ctxH.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctxH.save();
    ctxH.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    ctxH.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    ctxH.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2);
    ctxH.restore();
}
```

**[markE's Modified Demo (with animation)](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/JBCGC/3/)**